Website is resolving to wrong IP address for some ISPs only months after DNS changes. What can be the issue?
Our client's website https://www.amplehair.com/ is not working for some users using Optimum and Spectrum ISPs in NY area. For other ISPs the site works correctly. We have found out that if the user (who is facing the issue) sets his machines DNS Server to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 the site works correctly for them. But when they use their ISP's default DNS Server the site resolves to a wrong IP: 167.206.37.136 and the user gets an SSL Error. CURL error is:
curl -iv https://amplehair.com
Trying [2600:480:4000: c01:: 1]:443...
Trying 167.206.37.136:443. • •
* Connected to amplehair.com (167.206.37.136) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert. pem
CApath: none
* LibressL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to amplehair.com: 443
* Closing connection
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN in connection to amplehair.com: 443

Here the IP: 167.206.37.136 is not ours. The site is hosted on Webflow. The A record should resolve to:
Name:   amplehair.com
Address: 99.83.190.102
Name:   amplehair.com
Address: 75.2.70.75

The site is hosted on Webflow and is working for our development team and the client team also. Only one of the marketing team members found the issue when she was working from home.
To give you an history the client has bought this domain from some previous owner (squatter) and looks like the domain was blacklisted for hosting malware. So I had to request to a bunch of blacklists to review it again. I was hoping after being cleared from the blacklists this problem will go away. But the problem still persists.
I tried multiple DNS checking tools like intoDNS, MXToolbox, dig command and everything seems to be fine. May be I am not able to spot some subtle misconfiguration.
To add: The DNS are hosted on AWS on Route53 and are setup similar to many other projects I have. Never had such issue in the past.
It will be great help if someone could recheck the DNS config to see if something is wrong?

When I do a reverse lookup on the IP  167.206.37.136 from your cURL output: that shows: proxy.vip.orbgny.alticeusa.net.  - The word Proxy  in a hostname triggers all kinds of reasons/ danger signs / possibilities as to why web requests would get directed there rather than directly to a website .

In the past I have seen examples where domains that once were registered with an ISP (and that had a mail and/or web hosting package associated with that custom domain) were never deleted  from  that ISP’s DNS servers   and persisted long after the domain expired, the hosting package cancelled and/or the domain was transferred elsewhere.
All customers from that ISP would get old and no longer correct dns responses because their ISP name servers still consider themselves authoritative for that domain.
That can usually be confirmed by checking the SOA record.
An alternative can be the result of more malicious actions rather than negligence: DNS cache poisoning.
Both scenarios should be reported to the ISP concerned and generally cannot be resolved by you as the domain name owner/operator. (Getting the issue across and past well meaning but not overly technical first line support to the ISP’s actual network engineers may be challenging)

thanks for your input.
Google dig shows SOA record as: ns-286.awsdns-35.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
It is also correct.
Is there way to know if someone is intentionally trying DNS cache poisoning?

The  DNS  queries needed to debug issues like these need to be made using the resolvers of that ISP. Most ISP's place access controls on their resolvers allowing only their own customers to use them. That means that you probably can't use Google dig, or other web based tools but will need to test with tools installed locally on the computer(s) of the customers of the ISP that is serving incorrect DNS responses.  - Now, according to https://www.whatsmydns.net/dns/usa/optimum.html the DNS servers for Optimum are  167.206.112.138 and 167.206.7.4 -

Both of which don't have ACL's and return correct DNS results when I used them to resolve your domain name.

Yes finally we got through Optimum support and got them to correct it.

Thanks for your time and expertise.
